# How to test the return value from a function against multiple values without storing into a variable

Tags: c, conditional-statements

How could I achieve something like this ...

```
int main(void)
{
  if (f(x) == (a || b))
  {
     puts("Success");
  }
  return (0);
}
```

This would print Success if the return of f(x) is equal to a or b.
I know it is possible to store it in a variable but my question is:
"Could something like this be done by calling the f(x) function **only once without using a variable**?"

Edit 1: I'm not allowed to use the switch statement for this assignment

Edit 2: Could I set a range with only one expression like this?

```
if ( 2 < f(x) < 5)
```

Would this be valid (return type is int)?

Comment: `switch (f(x)) { case 'a' : ... case 'b': ... }` See example of use with `sscanf` in [How to read file line by line and get specific chars or ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60588632/how-to-read-file-line-by-line-and-get-specific-chars-or-ints/60588903#60588903) (under heading **Separating All Values**)

Comment: You could also write an auxiliary function: `int is_a_or_b(int x) { return (x == a) || (x == b); } ... if (is_a_or_b(f(x))) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but unfortunately I am not allowed to use the switch statement

Comment: Ok, then if the return is type `char` (or `int`) then use `if (strchr ("ab", f(x)) puts ("Success")`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `strchr ("ab", f(x))` matches on 3 values.  Maybe `memchr()`?

Comment: What type is `a, b` and return type of `f()`?

Comment: You need to share the full text of the assignment, not just dribble one tidbit at a time. And no, you can't compare a range like that, a range is checked with `if (2<x && x<5)`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica err...umm... the nul-character -- good catch? `memchr` it is.

Comment: Could I set a range like `if ( 2 < f(x) < 5)` -- NO, not in C.

Comment: The bad news: you'll need a temp variable. The good news: any modern compiler should be smart enough to optimize it out.

Comment: With more C abuse, code could begin with something like `f() * 0x100000000u` but the point is that even if it is _possible_, I see no clean way yet to do it without a simply temporary variable.

Answer (score 2):

> how to test for multiple return values from a function called once without storing into a variable (?)

Not really, but with some restrictions let us abuse C and assume `a, b` and `f()` return a character.

<sup>1</sup>Form a character array made up of `a` and `b` and search it using `memchr()`.  Inspired by [@David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60626747/c-how-to-test-for-multiple-return-values-from-a-function-called-once-without-s/60627014#comment107260521_60626747)  (It does not store the result of `f()` in a variable, but does call a function)

```
int main(void) {
  //         v-------------v compound literal
  if (memchr((char [2]){a,b}, f(x), 2)) {
     puts("Success");
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

---

I see OP added "return type is int" - Oh well.

---

`if ( 2 < f(x) < 5)` is valid code, but is does not do what OP wants.

It is like `if ( (2 < f(x)) < 5)` which compares `f(x)` with 2 and results in 0 or 1, which is always less than 5.

---

[Tough crowd](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tough%20crowd) tonight,  so how about the below.  Needs a bit of extension math for `int` overflow`, but is close.

```
abs(2*f(x) - (a+b)) == abs(a-b)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Not serious code suggestions for production code - use a temporary.

Comment: We can at least make it fun and `srand (time(NULL));` then `if (memchr ("ab", f(rand()), 2)) puts ("Success"); else puts ("Failure");` where `int f (int x) { return x % 3 + 'a'; }` ---- `:)`

Comment: `memchr((char [2]){a,b}, f(x), 2)` for the love of God why would you *ever* suggest something like this...................

Comment: @Marco Bonelli Why, because even though not practical, it is interesting to see how far one can go.  How about `abs(2*f(x) - (a+b)) == abs(a-b)`?  With `long long` extensions to handle overflow, that could work.  But this is all in [fun](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  A temporary is the way to go.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica this is a programming help Q&A website, not a code-golfing or obfuscation challenge... while I too find that funny I think you should make clear that this is not a serious answer.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Fair point.  I was thinking the "let us abuse C" was enough of a hint as to "not a serious answer.".  Perhaps too subtle.

Comment: It does not change too much - you have to save a & b or result of f(x). There is no way of avoiding it. memchr - saves both

Comment: I dunno, I kinda thought the compound-literal added a nice touch...

Answer (score 1):

This can obviously be done using a switch statement. Another way would be calling a function returning true or false with the first function value as input, another way could be a jump table or even `>` or bit checking using binary operators depending on a and b values (very common for testing multiple bit flags at once).

But really you shouldn't care about using or not using a variable in such cases. Current compilers are quite good putting temporary variables like that in registers.

EDIT: given the constraints, the most likely solution is using some bit fu, but it fully depends of values of a and b and c, etc. The common way is using powers of two as values to check. Then you can check a set of values in only one operation.

exemple: a = 1, b = 2, c = 4

```
if (f(x) & (1+2+4)) {...}
```

checks if we have a or b or c or a superposition of these values.

Answer (score 0):

C language does not such constructs. You need do save the result of the function or/and both `a` & `b`.

Of course you can:

```
int compare(int a, int b, int f)
{
    if(a == f || b == f) { puts("Success"); return 0;}
    return -1;
}

int f(int x)
{
    return x * x;;
}

int main()
{
    compare(5,8,f(3));
}
```

but of course it saves all the values as the functions parameters.